# Server responds with Stream data only once

Tags: node.js, express, streaming

I need to send data from big csv file over Http.Here is my code

```
const transformToJson = new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
        this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk));
        done();
    }
});

app.get('/api', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    stream.pipe(csvParser()).pipe(transformToJson).pipe(res);
    stream.on('open', () => console.log('open'))
    stream.on('close', () => console.log('closed'))
    req.on('aborted', () => stream.destroy());
})
```

The problem is when I send request on this endpoint I get data, but only once. If I send my request again(without server reloading), it almost instantly returns void.

```
            open
[start:run] closed
[start:run] open
[start:run] open
[start:run] open
[start:run] open
```

This is console logs on events Open and Close, as you can see, Readable stream closes only once and there are no errors also.

Will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to add a listenner for an error? `stream.on('error', (err) => console.log('error', err))`

Comment: Yes, no errors occurs

Comment: When the CSV is short, does it work?

Comment: In general, same blank response with 1 improvement, Readable stream now Opened then Closed every time

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my Transform stream. I created it one time, but had to do this with every request.

```
const transformToJson = () => new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
        this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk));
        done();
    }
});
```